# Accepting ip address as Input from user

Tags: python-2.7, networking, ip, ip-address, user-input

```
import os
import sys
import time
import pprint
import subprocess
from netaddr import *

print "(1).Ping specific target.\n(2).Ping sweep Subnet.\n(3).Exit"
choice = raw_input("Enter your choice:- ")
if choice == '1':
    host = raw_input("Enter IP address to scan: ")
    ip = IPAddress("host")
    print "accepted"
```

This is the first part of the program. I'm having problem while accepting an IP address from user as an input.
After executing i get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ping.py", line 13, in <module>
    ip = IPAddress("host")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netaddr/ip/__init__.py", line 308, in __init__
    'address from %r' % addr)
netaddr.core.AddrFormatError: failed to detect a valid IP address from 'host'
```

Using python 2.7.6

Answer (score 0):

You could use a try / except with a loop:

```
done = False
while not done:
    host = raw_input("Enter IP address to scan: ")
    try:
        ip = IPAddress("host")
        done = True
    except netaddr.core.AddrFormatError:
        print 'Invalid IP Address Format, please try again!'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the string `"host"` and not  the variable `host` in your assignment.

Change:

```
ip = IPAddress("host")
```

to

```
ip = IPAddress(host)
```